# add numbers to textbox

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<input type=text id="txtNum"/>

ex. of button
 <asp:Button ID="btnNum1" runat="server" CssClass="btnNumbers" Text="1"  />
<asp:Button ID="btnNum5" runat="server" CssClass="btnNumbers" Text="5" />
```

Basically I have a huge numberpad on my page using Buttons label from 0-9 and backspage and clear. This is going to be for a touchscreen device

I am not sure how to go about when a user touches button1 to place a '1' in my textbox. Then if they hit button5 my textbox value would append the 5 to the 1.

I would like to use javascript to perform this task so it does not do a postback for every button click please help.

Comment: append as in it should keep adding the values as a sum or just 1515... etc?

Comment: should just add 1515 or 5551 or what ever combination the user clicks

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to prevent the postback is to not use the asp.net button control. Just use standard html button

```
<button type="button" class="btnNumbers">1</button>
```

Then just attach to the `click` event for the button and append it's value to the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Add following method**
`$(document).ready(function() { $(".btnNumbers").click(function() { $("#txtNum").val($("#txtNum").val() +$(this).val()); return false; });
});`